# How does the staking reward calculation works?

Tags: staking

I've got right now about 100 tezos in my wallet and I delegated those to a baking service, assuming the yearly reward is about 6%.

If I buy 150 more tezos right now and put them in my wallet, will the value of the reward increase automatically `((100 + 150 tezos) * 6%)`? Will I have to delegate again?

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to re-delegate. Simply transfer the additional tez to the address. The new tokens are subject to the same waiting period as before. You will continue to earn rewards on the initial 100 XTZ, and after 7 cycles, you will start earning rewards on 250 XTZ.

Comment: @Anton please mark as answered

Answer (score 2):

You won't have to re-delegate because it's your wallet tz1 that delegates a baker, whatever the balance it has.